# Navigo not defined when using Browserify with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I can't get [Navigo (npm package)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/navigo) to work with Browserify and Gulp

My file structure (only including relevant stuff)

```
-index.html
-build
    -js
        -modules.js
        -routing.js
-js
    -modules.js
```

My bundle task in my gulpfile.js that uses browserify to be able to use Navigo in my actual routing.js file

```
gulp.task('bundlemods', function() {
    var bundleMods = browserify('./js/modules.js')
    .bundle()
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(source('modules.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});
```

Which outputs [the following modules.js file](http://pastebin.com/kWZUyyhQ)

Then in my routing.js I'm just trying to use Navigo as following:

```
function initRouting() {
    var rootUrl = null;
    var useHash = false;
    var router = new Navigo(rootUrl, useHash);

    router.on(function () {
        runHome();
    })
    .resolve();
}
```

However, this yields the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Navigo is not defined`

Also this is how my index.html file looks (relevant parts once again)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
/* stuff */
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        /* stuff */
    </main>
    <script src="build/js/modules.js"></script>
    <script src="build/js/routing.js"></script>
    /* other scripts */
</body>
</html>
```

What is the reason it is still undefined? How do I actually use Navigo once I've used Browserify to generate my modules file? Does it have something to do with global scopes or something else I'm missing?

Comment: post your repo or something, seems like you're not `requiring` packages the right way

Comment: Seems like the require was right but I just messed it up by not including it in the global scope. Eeeeeeheheh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course browserify prevent variables to leak in global scope. If you want to have it gloabally available you should explicitly attach it to global scope:

```
Navigo = require('navigo');
```

not using `var` key will attach *Navigo* var to global scope and when you browserify it, your global will be *window* and Navigo is available from anywhere.

If you don't want pollute global scope then you could just require it in *routing.js*:

```
var Navigo = require('navigo');
function initRouting() {
    var rootUrl = null;
    var useHash = false;
    var router = new Navigo(rootUrl, useHash);

    router.on(function () {
        runHome();
    })
    .resolve();
}
```

and then browserify this file instead.

Comment: You, my dear sir, is my saviour. Wow, I had so many problems along the way getting everything to work that I missed something as simple as this. Thank you so much! Also amazing answer that explains and not just shoves the answer in my face :D

Comment: @Clanket, Glad it helped.